# Render a dialog window for a particular element inside a map function

Tags: reactjs

I am mapping through an array and on click of an element I would like the details of the element be passed to a dialog window for display. Currently, because of the map function, I always get the last element (the last to be mapped)

I have tried to move the onClick function out of the map, but then I don't get information like waypoint and the index if so.

```
...
handleUpdateWaypointDialogOpen() {
    this.setState({
        updateWaypointDialogOpen: true,
    })
}

handleUpdateWaypointDialogClose() {
    this.setState({
        updateWaypointDialogOpen: false,
    })
}                     

    render() {
    return (

        array.map((waypoint, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    {
                            <UpdateWaypointDialog
                                open={updateWaypointDialogOpen}
                                onClose={this.handleUpdateWaypointDialogClose}
                                updateWaypoint={this.updateWaypoint}
                                index={i}
                                waypoint={waypoint} />
                    }
                    <Card
                        <CardContent>
                                                <Grid container spacing={16}>
                                                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <div onClick={this.handleUpdateWaypointDialogOpen}>
                            {waypoint.address}
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </CardContent >
                                        </Card >
                                    </div >
                                )
                            })
)}
```

I expect to have only the information of that particular waypoint be passed to the UpdateWaypointDialog and not the full array.

Comment: Your code basically open EVERY dialog on clicking any one of them. Because that `updateWaypointDialogOpen` is passed to all of them. Give each dialog their own open state.

Comment: @hackape good point, what do you mean "their own open state"?

Comment: typo, i mean "own state"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly,

But you can always  pass additional data from onClose or onClick

```
handleUpdateWaypointDialogOpen(event, waypoint) {
    this.setState({
        updateWaypointDialogOpen: true,
    })
}

handleUpdateWaypointDialogClose(waypoint) {
    this.setState({
        updateWaypointDialogOpen: false,
    })
}
```

```
<UpdateWaypointDialog
  open={updateWaypointDialogOpen}
  onClose={()=> this.handleUpdateWaypointDialogClose(waypoint)}
   updateWaypoint={this.updateWaypoint}
  index={i}
  waypoint={waypoint} />
```

```
<div onClick={(e)=>this.handleUpdateWaypointDialogOpen(e, waypoint)}>
  {waypoint.address}
</div>
```

Comment: not exactly. I am looking to only pass through props on UpdateWaypointDialog and only the element I clicked on, not each element, which is whatès happening right now due to the map function

Comment: @ksenia what is inside `array` variable?

Comment: array of objects, each containing address( string ), coordinates, lat and lon

Comment: and you want to pass this object to `UpdateWaypointDialog` ? is that right?

Answer (score 0):

array.map to another new Component, then move the `updateWaypointDialogOpen` into that new Component's state, also move `<div key={i}><UpdateWaypointDialog ...>` into new Component's render method. This way each Component has its own state, isolated from on another.